# Check if still connected to host with Javascript

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

In some place there is a policy which needs user to click button `Continue` to enter for example music streaming website.
Let's assume I want to use this website for a time longer than this policy accepts. After some period of time the music stops playing and after refreshing webpage - policy asks you for clicking `Continue` again, even if you have not left the page.

I'd like to make a script which would check if a connection still persists, but without website refreshing (because it plays music).

I've already created script which would click `Continue`, but don't know how to (and if it is possible) check connection, `if connection is broken` then refresh website and click `Continue`.

Can it be done with GreaseMonkey?

1. I enter http://deezer.com/
2. Script click `Continue` for me
3. I listen to music
4. Script is checking connection

   - if connection is ok go to 3.
5. Refresh website
6. Go to 2.

---

Click script:

```
if (document.title == 'Click continue')
{
  var a = document.getElementById('continue-text');
  a.children[1].click();
```

### }

If no policy then the return of page is:
`200 OK 318ms`
If policy goes on, then it returns:
`200 Forbidden 91ms`

Comment: post code for step 4. Do they have an API for this?

Comment: Step 4. is the missing code. No API, I believe this is specifically done to keep someone alive.

Comment: Isn't there something like you request some url and you'll see 401 instead of 200?

Comment: Different page shows up if I'd request after the period of time. But the page doesn't reload itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the connection like this:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
               // this might need some customisation:
               var connected = document.getElementById("id_of_the_continue_button") ? true : false;
               if (!connected) {
                   reconnect();
               }
           }
           else {
               reconnect();
           }
        }
    }
    // here you'll need a relevant url:
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://deezer.com/", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work with my case. I believe site will not return 400, because another site will load instead of this. But will check this out tomorrow.

Comment: Then why did younwrite: "Different page shows up if I'd request after the period of time."?

Comment: One does not negate the other. The URL stays `http://deezer.com/` But there is different content, which is asking you to click `Continue` then redirect to desired website.

Comment: So you should check for the id of the Continue button. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Ok, let's see if it works. I need to wait another hour, because the period is ~1h